# Add image to video using ffmpeg , the output file can't be played

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

I need to watermark a mp4 video ,  but it is not working , It has bothered me for a week,please help me 
here is my code:

```
ffmpeg -i sss01.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=10:10" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4
```

****This command was executed successfully ,but The size of output.mp4 only is 50kb and it cann't play. the command detail:****

```
>  ffmpeg -i sss01.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=10:10" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4  
 ffmpeg version git-2017-06-08-a3b5b60 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers  
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)  
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-openssl  
  libavutil      55. 63.100 / 55. 63.100  
  libavcodec     57. 96.101 / 57. 96.101  
  libavformat    57. 72.101 / 57. 72.101  
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100  
  libavfilter     6. 91.100 /  6. 91.100  
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101  
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100  
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100  
Input #0, png_pipe, from 'watermark.png':  
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A  
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 215x115 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 43:23], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc  
Invalid file index 1 in filtergraph description [0:v][1:v] overlay=10:10.  
[root@localhost wwwroot]# ffmpeg -i sss01.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=10:10" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4  
ffmpeg version git-2017-06-08-a3b5b60 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers  
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)  
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-openssl  
  libavutil      55. 63.100 / 55. 63.100  
  libavcodec     57. 96.101 / 57. 96.101  
  libavformat    57. 72.101 / 57. 72.101  
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100  
  libavfilter     6. 91.100 /  6. 91.100  
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101  
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100  
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100  
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'sss01.mp4':  
  Metadata:  
    major_brand     : isom  
    minor_version   : 512  
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41  
    encoder         : Lavf57.72.101  
  Duration: 00:03:09.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1547 kb/s  
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1416 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 48 tbc (default)  
    Metadata:  
      handler_name    : VideoHandler  
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)  
    Metadata:  
      handler_name    : SoundHandler  
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s (default)  
    Metadata:  
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler  
Input #1, png_pipe, from 'watermark.png':  
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A  
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 215x115 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 43:23], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc  
File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y  
Stream mapping:  
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay:main  
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay  
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)  
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)  
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help  
[libx264 @ 0xb4ee7e0] using SAR=1/1  
[libx264 @ 0xb4ee7e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2  
[libx264 @ 0xb4ee7e0] profile High, level 4.0  
[libx264 @ 0xb4ee7e0] 264 - core 150 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00  
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':  
  Metadata:  
    major_brand     : isom  
    minor_version   : 512  
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41  
    encoder         : Lavf57.72.101  
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 24 fps, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc (default)  
    Metadata:  
      encoder         : Lavc57.96.101 libx264  
    Side data:  
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1  
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)  
    Metadata:  
      handler_name    : SoundHandler  
frame=   20 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.81 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=   30 fps= 29 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.23 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=   37 fps= 23 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.50 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=   42 fps= 11 q=28.0 size=      40kB time=00:00:01.71 bitrate= 190.6kbits/frame=   44 fps= 10 q=28.0 size=      46kB time=00:00:01.81 bitrate= 210.2kbits/Killedd=0.41x
```

Comment: You forgot the `-i` before `sss01.mp4`.

Comment: Not in the 2nd run.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard sorry, I missed the copy,I used this parameter

Comment: @Mulvya I do not understand what you mean

Comment: @StevenChen He was responding to my comment. Apparently I missed the second `ffmpeg` command in the code block which did include the missing `-i`.

Comment: So what is the cause of my problem, I can not find the reason has been more than a week

Answer (score 0):

i change the source file,it work properly.  i believe that the souce file contain Subtitle stream so that problem.